# How to represent this one-dimentional movement in math?

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, physics, word-problem, smooth-functions

I'm struggling trying to convert this movement behavior into an equation.

For future reference, this is as a result of searching for a solution for a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9359652).

Thank you @eyeballfrog for helping me reformulate my question.

## Setup

Starting with the most basic scenario for this problem, let $A$, $C$, $D$ & $F$ be unique arbitrary points, where $AC$ & $DF$, each represent a line segment with a moving point along them, being $B$ & $E$ respectively. So far, $\frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{DE}{EF} = r$.

Now, since $AC < DF$, we define a new point $G$, such that $AB = DG$.
Hypothetically, if $AC > DF$, we'd have $DE = AG$.

At this point, by defining the $X_i$ sequence of points as $GX_{i+1}/X_{i+1}X_i = r; X_0 = E$, we could generate an arbitrary number of new points; for this simple case, $0 <= i <= 2$.

Last, but not least, $AC$ & $DF$ are parallel between each other, and $AC \ne DF$.

## Question(s)

Given the above, the question is: Would it be possible to obtain a $f_i(x)$, which accepts as input a value in $[0, 1]$ and returns $x(X_i)$ -- The $x$ coordinate of $X_i$?

And moreover: Would there be a way to expand such reasoning to allow for $N > 2$ line segments, such that $h_{ij}(x) = x(X_{ij})$

#### Simple static diagram

[image: Simple diagram]

Where the percentage slider represents $100r$.

## Motivation

The main idea behind this, as stated in [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9359652), it's to move two points relatively, along their own line segment, attempting to keep both points reasonably close/aligned each other, despite difference in lengths, which, due to the relative nature of the movement, ends up creating a difference in pace for every point, consequently shifting points away.

Additionally, all points must start & finish at the same time.

---

For the sake of completeness, and as a proof of concept, here's how it looks when using $4$ -- $j$ segments, at $9$ different «softness» -- $i$ levels, including «stock» level, $[0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 101]$, from right to left (or from red moving point to yellow point).

Note how the shortest line segment doesn't have more than 3 points: That's because every other line segment pivot depends on its moving point; since it doesn't depend on any other segment, there's no need for more than 3 points on it.

After all, the ultimate objective of all this, its to pick a single «softness» level -- color, and discard the rest.

#### Extended dynamic behavior

[image: Full diagram]

Comment: This is just too much to take in, especially with another question to take into account. It isn't even obvious to me what the question is, or if there is a question there at all. You might need to think this through more and reduce it to some short problem that really gets at the essence of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ouch, I'm sorry to hear that. Unfortunately, this is the best I could do to «reduce» my problem to the bare minimum essentials. In fact, reading my other question is entirely optional, I just linked them for future reference; admittedly, I reckon I may be lacking more math terminology, or maybe I'm not using it adequately.

Regarding my question, the title says it all.  Oh, and many thanks for taking your time to reply.

Comment: OK I think what you're saying is that you have line segments $AC$ and $DF$ and points on those lines $B$ and $E$ respectively such that $AB/BC$ and $DE/EF$ have the same ratio $r$. Then you also have point $G$ such that $AB = DG$. You want to make a sequence of points $X_i$ such that $X_0 = E$ and $GX_{i+1}/X_{i+1}X_{i} = r$.

Comment: You should spend more time on the setup of the problem.  Tell your Readers how many points are moving (for which you want an "equation").  One gets pretty far into the text before discovering that it is not a case of wanting one equation for the motion of one point, and this causes a need to backtrack in parsing the information.

Comment: @hardmath, Yeah, you have a point there, but I did my best; apologies. Nonetheless, I'll try once again to reformulate my question.

Comment: Wow, you nailed it @eyeballfrog!. I had to read it twice to make sure what you wrote was what I asked, but you're totally right. Definitely, math notation isn't one of my strengths, you managed to extract, convert and compress the whole idea.

Based on your comment, I'll expand my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $AC$ is of unit length, $DF$ is of length $d$, and $AB = r$. Then along $DF$, $DG = r$, $DE = r d$, and $GE = r(d-1)$. The next point $X_1$ is at a ratio $r$ of the distance between $G$ and $E$, so $DX_1 = DG + r\cdot GE = r + r^2(d-1)$. Similarly, $DX_2 = DG + r\cdot GX_1 = r + r^3(d-1)$. At this point you've probably spotted that this is a geometric series: $DX_n = r + r^{n+1}(d-1) = r[1+r^n(d-1)]$.